# nvarchar to SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

can I convert nvarchar(max) to sql ?

like here

```
SELECT [RecTime], [Name],
   CAST(CASE WHEN 
    -- <logics>
    EXEC([SQL]) -- Or NvarcharToSql ...
    -- </logics>
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [Value]
FROM EventIncidentsStates
GROUP BY [RecTime], [Name], [SQL]
```

and sql contains sql logics ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't embed a stored proc call or EXEC in a SELECT

You can use a scalar udf is you don't care about performance, but not if it is dynamic SQL

You'd have to loop or some such: but it isn't clear what you're trying to do. You asked how to do your chosen solution, rather than stating your problem/requirement

Comment: do you think I must start try to ask about my problem with link on this question ?

Comment: In this case, yes please. We may be able to offer a solution if know your goal.